# SearchKick x vs ×

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a few questions related to SearchKick, but they seem closely related so I'm going to ask both:

1. How can I distinct between `×` (times) and `x`? The proper version in the database is times, but people will definitely type 'x'. When I add `['x', '×']` as synonyms it gives an error `× was completely eliminated by analyzer`
2. My database mostly deals with model numbers which include hyphens.

People can type these 3 ways:

- `abc-123`
- `abc123`
- `abc 123`

How might I go about doing this? It seems the hyphens and spaces make quite a problem. It should allow both, but the problem is these numbers can appear in the same column as the name itself:

`ABC-123 Camera Lense 40mm`

So in this case I want to allow `abc123`, `abc 123`, `abc-123` but I dont want to allow `cameralense`.

Thanks!